# Swift Version 5, SwiftyJSON

Tags: swift, swifty-json

Build system information
error: SWIFT_VERSION '5.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2. (in target 'SwiftyJSON')

how can I deal with it?

Comment: Can I give you an advice? Don't use SwiftyJSON in Swift 4+

Comment: You are getting this error because you need to update your Xcode Version and migrate your project to Swift 5, if you want to point to this new version. Projects using Swift 5 can only be built with Xcode 10.2

Comment: @RobertDresler care to elaborate? Because of `Codable`?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I mean because of `Codable`. Ofc SwiftyJSON can be helpful in other cases

Comment: @RobertDresler what would be your suggestion instead of `SwiftyJSON`?

Answer (score 2):

[SwiftyJSON v4.3.0](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/releases) supports Swift 5. Check your `Podfile` to make sure you’re getting the latest release. You may need to update your Pods (with `pod update`) to make sure you’ve got the latest versions.

Also, you might consider retiring SwiftyJSON and using [`JSONEncoder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder)/[`JSONDecoder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder) instead. See [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) or the [Using JSON with Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/using_json_with_custom_types) sample for more information.

---

If, on the other hand, you are not using Swift 5 yet, just configure your `Podfile` indicate that you want to use SwiftyJSON v4.2.0. E.g.

```
target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.2'
end
```

Comment: I'm using Swiftyjson 4.3 but i still get the error message in Xcode that Swift 5 is unsupported by Swiftyjson...

Comment: Then you should post a question, showing us what we need to do, step by step, in a blank project, to reproduce your issue. But I just created blank project, did `pod init`, added `pod 'SwiftyJSON'` to my `Podfile`, did `pod install`, and then opened my `.xcworkspace`, and could `import SwiftyJSON` in my Swift 5 based blank project without incident. I even did `let data = #"{"foo": "bar"}"#.data(using: .utf8)!; let json = try! JSON(data: data); print(json)` and it worked fine. It’s going to be hard to figure out what’s wrong unless you can show us how to reproduce. So post your own question.

Comment: I'll start over from scratch to see if I can find where i screwed up.  thanks/

Comment: @jmh: `~> 4.2` means all 4.x that is less than 5.0 (including 4.3 which uses Swift 5). To limit it to 4.2.x (less than 4.3), you need to write `~> 4.2.0`. Or just use the exact version `4.2.0` without the `~>` since that's the last version that does not use Swift 5

Answer (score 0):

Either change the build target of your project to Swift 4.x or wait until the project gets support for Swift 5 (you can check that on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON))

Answer (score 0):

I get this error too when i tried to pod lint or push.

```
error: SWIFT_VERSION '5.0' is unsupported, supported versions are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2.
```

I have to stay on xcode 10.1 ans use cocoapods 1.5.3, but on a fresh install (new mac) I received the same error.

Here is my solution:

After comparing my 'gem list' with an other mac, I found that the gem xcodeproj was very high (1.12.0).

So, I installed a lower version required by cocoapods (1.5.3)

```
"sudo gem install xcodeproj -v 1.5.7"
```

and remove the never

```
"sudo gem uninstall xcodeproj -v 1.12.0"
```

Wrongs fine now, I cant lint and push my pods.